# How can i replace node text (ANLR, AST)

Tags: c#, antlr, transformation, abstract-syntax-tree

Transforming source using ANTLR (AST, C#)

I am trying to transform source text replacing  "/// Text here (trace)" to "WriteLog(modulename, functionname, trace, 'Text here');"

So i am trying to replace nodetext

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tree.ChildCount; i++){
   if (Tree.GetChild(i).Text == NODE_LOGGING)
       Tree.GetChild(i).GetChild(0).Text = MyReplace(Tree.GetChild(i).GetChild(0).Text);
   else ....

}
```

but property Text is readonly, so it does not work.
Is it possible to change node text, and then get modified source text or that way is hopefully ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the String getText() method of CommonTree returns only the associated token text:

```
public String getText() {
    if ( token==null ) {
        return null;
    }
    return token.getText();
}
```

To get the token you can call Token getToken() of CommonTree and set the token text via void setText(String text) of Token.

Comment: In my grammar, there are could be couple tokens in one AST's node... Could you place here an example replacing node text?